# Strapi API endpoint syntax for querying boolean fields?

Tags: strapi

[The Strapi documentation is apparently silent on this,](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/content-api/parameters.html#parameters) unless I am missing something. The examples shown there only query the fields by string or numeric values.

What I have tried myself that didn't work:

```
http://localhost:1337/restaurants?vegan=true
http://localhost:1337/restaurants?vegan=1
http://localhost:1337/restaurants?vegan=0
http://localhost:1337/restaurants?vegan=null
```

I understand this is tricky because who's to say that `true` doesn't mean the literal string `"true"`. So how do I query boolean fields' value via the API endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, using the `query param` as `true` or `false` like you mentioned above works fine in strapi.
The problem you might be facing is how the default Boolean values are stored in the database. If you are using `MYSQL` databse with strapi , I checked the boolean type field is stored as `TINYINT`, and even if you select the default value as `FALSE` or `TRUE` while adding a new boolean field for a `CONTENT-TYPE` from UI, it is stored as null in the database (which i think is a bug in strapi, it should be `0` or `1` and not null). Refer the images below

[image]

[image]

So as a workaround, when adding a new record for your content-type, select the boolean field as `ON`, and   save it, and once the record is saved you can edit the record (if you want the boolean value to be false) and save it as `OFF`. This would change the value to `0` in the database and you can then search the record through api endpoint using `true` or `false`. For eg `http://localhost:1337/restaurants?vegan=true` or `http://localhost:1337/restaurants?vegan=false`.

[image]

[image]